# Making the sound card's power_save parameter permanent

Tags: sound, 20.04, soundcard

Since I upgraded to ubuntu 20.04, I have a pulsing noise most likely due to a capacitor discharge in my speaker, and I have been able to solve the problem by changing the sound card power_save parameter to 0 by using the line

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

found on the site
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/weird-static-noise-in-headset-on-ubuntu-20-04-a-4175681180/.
But each time I boot, I have to do the manipulation again. How could I turn this parameter to 0 by default ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Make a file in the /etc/modprobe.d directory, named:
audio_disable_powersave.conf

Put this line in it:
options snd_hda_intel power_save=0

save/exit and reboot.

A workaround, but it'll do until this is addressed.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot anonymous

Comment: As I'm using an USB sound card I had to replace `snd_hda_intel` by `snd_usb_audio` worked perfectly, thx a lot !